# Maven dependency not resolved due to version mismatch in Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, build, eclipse-plugin

I have a Java project that I want to build using Gradle and which uses Eclipse libraries. Within Eclipse there is no problem as the libraries are already shipped as plugins. However, the Maven resolution of dependencies does not work properly.

For example, a required package org.eclipse.ui.workbench can be found in the [Eclipse repositories](https://repo.eclipse.org/#nexus-search;quick~org.eclipse.ui.workbench). However, several transitive dependencies fail with e.g. the following error, although the message already shows there is a suitable version available:

```
Could not find any version that matches org.eclipse.scout.sdk.deps:org.eclipse.core.runtime:[3.12.0,3.12.1).
  Versions that do not match:
      3.12.0.v20160606-1342
```

I guess the part after the minor version is causing the trouble and for whatever reason Gradle(?)/Maven assumes `3.12.0 > 3.12.0.v20160606-1342`. But how to solve this issue as there are no other artifacts available?